# Setting brightness of IR light in Kinect One (v2)

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I've written an application based upon the Kinect One (known as Kinect v2, which is not the Kinect for Xbox 360).
After some testing, I got errors in my data, due to the brightness of IR lights.

In both IRview, and DepthView, the too bright reflections cannot be handled
I can put a sunglass in front of the IR camera, and all still works.
Including depth sensing still works, as it is based on time of flight not the brightness of the light.

So using a sunglass sure is a hack that works, but as a coder i dont like that. Is it possible to set the brightness by use of the SDK or some other coding Hack?

I've been thinking that maybe the lights will disable, or dimm their brightness when using the long IR reader 
ea working with:

```
infraredFrameLongExposureReader.FrameArrived += InfraredFrameLongExposureReader_FrameArrived;
```

But i could not see much of a difference between the long exposure version and the normal exposure methods.

So I'm kinda out of clues... is there a way to adjust the IR brightness??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.** Not in the official Mircosoft SDK, not in libfreenect2, the open source SDK for Kinect2.

You can't change any of the hardware settings. Not the IR brightness, not the exposure time of either IR or RGB camera, nothing.

Using the long exposure IR frame, you will get an even brighter IR image, but nothing else will change.

So your best bet is the hardware hack you already figured out: put sunglasses over the IR camera (or the IR emitters).

Comment: ok hm to bad, sometimes i read those MSresearch articles, convincing me that they have some kind of lower level access to the device, but well i believe you, its not in the official sdk, thanks

Comment: @HenningJ: can you provide some reference from MSDN or any other official Microsoft source?

Comment: @user3800527: sure, some papers published by Microsoft Research were using different firmwares, allowing them to control some camera settings. But there is nothing publicly available.

Comment: @VitoShadow: My main reference is the SDK (documentation), which provides methods to [read some camera parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinect.icolorcamerasettings.aspx), but no methods to change any of them. There also were some comments by Microsoft employees to that effect in the [official support forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=kinectv2sdk).